# Persistent Volume Issue on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

So I am trying to create a persistent volume on GKE with the definition below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01-3gi
  labels:
    env: prod
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - 'ReadWriteOnce'
  storageClassName: standard
```

However when I try to apply this, I get the error message shown below:

```
➜ kubectl apply -f pv-1.yaml
The PersistentVolume "pv01-3gi" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type
```

My understanding is that the volume type is indicated by the storage class which is set to standard (which is a default storage class offered by GKE

```
➜ kubectl get storageclass
NAME                 PROVISIONER            AGE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   16d
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, in this particular example you're missing the part responsible for matching the `PV` with `gce-pd` disk. You can fix that by adding to `spec` following part: `gcePersistentDisk` with `pdName` and `fsType` parameters. You can find how exactly it should look here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that Storage Classes on directly provisioned Persistent Volumes **only serve the purpose to make it possible to reference those volumes via Persistent Volume Claims**!

The intention here is that a system administrator sets up a bunch of Persistent Volumes and deals with the details of referencing hard drive devices outside of the cluster. Then an application developer can reference those volumes via Persistent Volume Claims, by stating figuratively speaking: "Please find me a volume of StorageClass SSD with at least 5GB storage".

In other words, if you create a PV directly, please make sure you provide the exact configuration including the reference to the physical storage device.

Comment: This answered my question perfectly. I thought that the storage class name on a PV would create a drive of the specified capacity in that storage class (using the provisioner defined in the storage class). So I was a little confused why I was getting a volume type not present message when it could be pulled from the storage class definition.

Answer (score 0):

If using a dynamic provisioner, there is no need to create the PV on your own.

Just create a PVC with storage class and GKE will automatically provide the PV with the requested storage size.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ssd-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10
  storageClassName: ssd
```

Comment: I understand that but I am trying to figure out what the issue is with this PV definition

Comment: @aj31 https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the volume type in `spec`. for example, i have added `nfs` type  here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01-3gi
  labels:
    env: prod
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  nfs: 
    path: /opt/nfs 
    server: nfs.f22 
    readOnly: false
```